# How to check if a directory exists in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` to get a directory entry.

I need to know if this directory exists to delete it before proceeding.

When doing...

```
const path = cordova.file.dataDirectory + directoryName;

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, (directoryEntry) => {
    console.log(directoryEntry);
});
```

... I get a `DirectoryEntry` object, but other than an empty `name` there doesn't seem to be a way to check whether it exists or not.

This is the only `DirectoryEntry` available documentation but it's seriously outdated:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova/file/directoryentry/directoryentry.html

The current docs of the File plugin don't have much information on `DirectoryEntry`:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

So how can I know if a directory exists using Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't pass an error callback to `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()`.

When passing it I get a `FileError` with code `1` equivalent to `NOT_FOUND_ERR`.

Sadly there is no documentation available for `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and I had to resort to reading the source code.

The signature of the function is as follows:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs it

```
//check if a directory exists
    async dirExists (absolutePath) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                absolutePath,
                (dir) => {
                    console.log(dir);
                    resolve(true);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    resolve(false);
                });
        });
    }
```